# Python What is the difference between calling "self.property" and creating a method that returns "self.property"?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Lets say I have a class like this:

```
class SomeClass:
    some_property = 'property'

    def get_some_property(self):
        return self.some_property

    def some_method(self):
        pass
```

What is difference (if any) between `var1` and `var2` in the following:

```
    def some_method(self):
        var1 = self.some_property
        var2 = self.get_some_property()
```

For a less abstract example of this question, consider the `FormMixin` class in `django.generic.views.edit`, which looks something like this:

```
class FormMixin(ContextMixin):
    """Provide a way to show and handle a form in a request."""
    initial = {}
    form_class = None
    success_url = None
    prefix = None

    ...

    def get_form_class(self):
        """Return the form class to use."""
        return self.form_class

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        """Return an instance of the form to be used in this view."""
        if form_class is None:
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
        return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
```

The method `get_form_class` returns the `form_class` property of self, but isn't this exactly the same as calling `self.form_class`?

Comment: The idea is to allow developers that subclass these generic views to be able to override this behaviour. Yes, the default case is just to return the attribute but in some cases you may want the form_class returned to be dynamic

Comment: @IainShelvington couldn't you still dynamically change the `form_class` by calling `self.form_class = 'something'` without using `get_form_class`?

Comment: Yes, that's possible but where would you put such code? It's nice and clean to have code that dynamically gets the form_class in a method named get_form_class. It's a design decision at the end of the day

Answer (score 1):

Using functions makes it easy to have different classes with the same interface, but different implementations. Some implementations may store the value in an attribute, while others have to compute it.

A classic demonstration of this is two classes for representing vectors, either using cartesian or polar coordinates. By accessing the coordinates using methods, you can interchange them.

```
import math

class cartesian_vector():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def getX(self):
        return self.x
    def getY(self):
        return self.y
    def getR(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.x**2 + self.y**2)
    def getTheta(self):
        return math.atan(self.y/self.x)

class polar_vector():
    def __init__(self, r, theta):
        self.r = f
        self.theta = theta
    def getX(self):
        return self.r * math.cos(self.theta)
    def getY(self):
        return self.r * math.sin(self.theta)
    def getR(self):
        return self.r
    def getTheta(self):
        return self.theta
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Indeed, many OO languages have "getters" and "setters" that allow you to customize attribute access. But this is the basic principle.